# Get the name of the source branch from which the PR was merged

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

I use Azure DevOps as my CI/CD platform and I am currently working on developing a YAML file that requires the name of the source branch from which the PR was merged.

For example: If I open a PR from branch `feature` to branch `master`; then when I merge this PR; my pipeline gets triggered. In this trigger, I would like to get the source branch name which in my case is `feature`.

I've looked into `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch` and also `Build.SourceBranch`; but these options are only useful if I either have a PR open or when to get the target branch name upon merging (at least in my case)

Is there some documentation that I can refer to for getting the source branch name in the YAML when a PR is merged?

Comment: But what if there was direct push to your target branch? Or changes was batched so your build is running for multiple PR's?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such variable available in DevOps, but you could try a workaround:

1. After you merge a PR, the merge commit will say something like "Merged PR XXXX". When building from `master` branch, you can get that commit message (i.e. via `git log`) and parse it to find PR Id.
2. Knowing PullRequest's Id, you can use [DevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get its details. One of the properties will be `sourceRefName` - which is the source branch you're looking for.